# WSO2 Product - Security Advisory guideline

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Sometime I receive Security Advisory Email from [WSO2 Security Team](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Security/Acknowledgments) like below.

> Security is one of our highest priorities.That’s why we proactively
> look for ways to improve it. We have identified a few critical
> vulnerabilities for the following product and would like to share the
> recommendation in order to mitigate the issue.

I don't know what are all the basic steps required to apply this security in WSO2 Product like WSO2 EI etc.

Reference Link from Email:

[WSO2 EI Security Advisory 1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Security/Security+Advisory+WSO2-2021-1260)

[WSO2 EI Security Advisory 2](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Security/Security+Advisory+WSO2-2021-1261)

Can any WSO2 Expert share the useful guideline for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the WSO2 Subscription you can use Update 2.0 to get the latest security updates and it will provide a summary of the applied updates. The summary contains information about the updates and instructions if you need to make any configuration changes to the specific WSO2 product.

Comment: Hi @Shanaka Premarathna,
Thanks for your answer. if possible kindly share much more information about WSO2 Subscription.

Comment: You can refer to the documentation https://wso2.com/subscription/